# How disable/enable tapping on trackpad/touchpad on Lenovo yoga 2 Pro windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

I have a yoga 2 pro and it was annoying while I move the cursor on touchpad getting tapped or dragged the files. Did a lots of searching and found nothing. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10, Go to mouse setting -> Additional mouse option -> (In mouse properties you will found additional option, i.e driver something like ELAMN) -> And enable check box as "Disable when external USB pointing device plugin

Answer (score 0):

Finally I answered myself. Click start-Setting-Mouse & touchpad - Additional Mouse options-Settings-Uncheck Enable Tapping - OK - OK.